# pandas single column value to multiple column headers with formatted values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert a single column `extra` into three new headers based on the string value of `extra` formatted as `<column name>: <column value(s)>, ..., <column name>: <column value(s)>` where `column name` is the new column and `column value(s)` can be an arbitrary column value such as list, float or string.

I am working with the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
 
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "subject": [1,1],
        "extra": ["category: app, datasets: [\"X\", \"Y\"], acc: [0.8, 0.9]",
                  "category: dev, datasets: [\"Z\", \"Y\"], acc: [0.7, 0.95]"],
    }
)
```

desired output:

```
   subject category datasets          acc
0        1      app   [X, Y]   [0.8, 0.9]
1        1      dev   [Z, Y]  [0.7, 0.95]
```

and then `df.explode(["acc", "datasets"])` will give the final desired result

```
   subject category datasets   acc
0        1      app        X   0.8
0        1      app        Y   0.9
1        1      dev        Z   0.7
1        1      dev        Y  0.95
```

Comment: @enke looks like YAML to me.

Comment: @enke zotero export bibliography to csv. Custom fields are not supported apparently so not much I can do to change the format. The solution I have is to place everything in the "extra" column.

Comment: Note that the formatting is done myself so it could just as well be a query string for instance: `category=app&datasets=[X,Y]&acc=[0.8,0.9]`

Comment: @Kevin I submitted an answer below. I used a regular expression to make it valid yaml, but it would be better if you could change the field separator to a newline instead of `,` so that hack wouldn't be necessary. Even better, make the format be valid *JSON* and use `json.loads` instead of `re.sub` and `yaml.load`!

Comment: @richardec Thanks for the suggestion. Using the json format `'{"category": "app", "datasets": ["X", "Y"], "acc": [0.8, 0.9]}'`, It seems possible to get my desired output from `pd.json_normalize(df["extra"].apply(lambda x: json.loads(x)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pyyaml`](https://pypi.org/project/pyyaml):

```
import yaml
extracted_df = pd.json_normalize(df['extra'].apply(lambda x: yaml.load(re.sub(r',\s*(\w+:)', '\n\\1', x), Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)))
new_df = pd.concat([df.drop('extra', axis=1), extracted_df], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
   subject category datasets          acc
0        1      app   [X, Y]   [0.8, 0.9]
1        1      dev   [Z, Y]  [0.7, 0.95]
```